# Server Host or Raspberry Pi for Quick Books

Tags: linux, windows, networking, raspberry-pi

Two questions, interrelated.

1. Does anyone know if Quick Books can be run on a raspberry pi 4? For a machine that's *only* used for quick books in the house, I figured this would be a cheap alternative to purchasing a new windows machine to replace the dying unit.
2. If not, how could I go installing quick books on my Windows 10 Pro Machine (acting as a home server, possibly being converted to Ubunutu in the near future) and then having a Raspberry Pi access the program and run it off the network? One very crude solution would be to use something like Teamviewer on the Pi to get into the other machine but that doesn't *really* accomplish what I want efficiently.... there must be a better way. Note: this would be a preferred avenue if people have ideas over option 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBooks Desktop works well on Windows, OK on MAC OS, and not on Linux.  The server manager (if you need multi-user) works on Windows Server.  So your options here are limited to Windows for effective use. QuickBooks Desktop will not see much in the way of Feature Updates going forward.

QuickBooks Online is web based (cloud based) and the client installs on most platforms.  This approach will be much better for your environment. I suggest you adopt this approach.

Comment: So you're saying my copy of quick books is near the end of life? :( 

Basically I was asking because I have a Pi sitting here and a Windows Server running in the closet. I don't use the older "book keeping" computer more than two days a month for just Quick Books and given the option, I'd prefer to keep my quick books data stored on an external (as it is now) so when I'm not using the program, it can't be hacked (physically unplugged).

Comment: Yes, QB Desktop is end of design life. It will be be used for several more years, but Windows only. Multiple OS platforms will be accomplished with QB Online. For the Desktop product, you must keep it on a secure platform.

Comment: I was kind of hoping there was something similar to the old RemoteApp that windows used to have, but with the ability to have a raspberry pi client and a windows 10 host.

Comment: No Limux client for QB, and in any event it must operate in a true client server environment as the existing Windows client cannot directly remote into a remote database.

Comment: Just so you know, I am a QB Pro Advisor and do this work for clients.

Comment: Can QB Online be setup to store data only locally and not in cloud services?

Comment: QB Online is designed to work in the cloud.  It is the Desktop product that is locally oriented. This is why I suggest you use the Online version. It is much more flexible and adapts well to your use.

Comment: I do appreciate that and I don't have an issue with the cloud computing aspect, I just don't want my data stored on the cloud....and that's what I'm trying to figure out how to work around.

Comment: Then you need to use a Windows environment for working traditionally. Linux will not work around this.

Comment: And will intuit be providing a method for this workaround in a few years when the desktop version is gone?

Comment: Only as long as the desktop version survives - I do not know precisely how long that will be.